# case statement in where clause - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to add a case or if statement in the where clause of my SQL query.
I have a table of journey times with a start and end date, and a boolean field for each day to signify where the journey happens on that day. Here is what I have so far, but I'm getting incorrect syntax errors:

```
declare @date datetime
set @Date = '05/04/2012' 
declare @day nvarchar(50)
set @day = 'Monday'

Select * From Times
WHERE (StartDate <= @Date) AND (EndDate >= @Date)
CASE WHEN @day = 'Monday' THEN
 AND (Monday = 1)
WHEN @day = 'Tuesday' THEN
AND (Tuesday = 1)
ELSE
AND (Wednesday = 1) 
END
```

Comment: Looks to me as if you have a design issue on the table, There is no way you should ever have columns Monday, tuesday, Wed, etc. You shoudlhavea daya column and populate it with the day you want or a numeric value that is a lookup to the day ayou want. If more than one day is applicable, then use a related table.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You don't need `case` in the `where` statement, just use parentheses and `or`:

```
Select * From Times
WHERE StartDate <= @Date AND EndDate >= @Date
AND (
    (@day = 'Monday' AND Monday = 1)
    OR (@day = 'Tuesday' AND Tuesday = 1)
    OR Wednesday = 1
)
```

Additionally, your syntax is wrong for a case. It doesn't append things to the string--it returns a single value. You'd want something like this, if you were actually going to use a `case` statement (which you shouldn't):

```
Select * From Times
WHERE (StartDate <= @Date) AND (EndDate >= @Date)
AND 1 = CASE WHEN @day = 'Monday' THEN Monday
             WHEN @day = 'Tuesday' THEN Tuesday
             ELSE Wednesday
        END
```

And just for an extra umph, you can use the `between` operator for your date:

```
where @Date between StartDate and EndDate
```

Making your final query:

```
select
    * 
from 
    Times
where
    @Date between StartDate and EndDate
    and (
        (@day = 'Monday' and Monday = 1)
        or (@day = 'Tuesday' and Tuesday = 1)
        or Wednesday = 1
    )
```

Comment: Thanks Eric - that is perfect :)

Comment: @Eric This will slow down query

Answer (score 5):

**simply do the  `select`:**

```
Select * From Times
WHERE (StartDate <= @Date) AND (EndDate >= @Date) AND
((@day = 'Monday' AND (Monday = 1))
OR (@day = 'Tuesday' AND (Tuesday = 1))
OR (Wednesday = 1))
```

Comment: It would be uncouth for me to downvote you, but you can use `case` in the `where` clause. You just can't use it like the OP is trying to do.

Comment: In Microsoft SQL Server, you can indeed use a `CASE` in a `WHERE` clause. Try this - parses & executes just fine (on SQL 2008 R2):  "select * from sys.tables t
where case when t.schema_id = 1 then 1
else 0 end = 1"

Answer (score 1):

A `CASE` statement is an expression, just like a boolean comparison.  That means the 'AND' needs to go before the 'CASE' statement, not within it.:

```
Select * From Times
WHERE (StartDate <= @Date) AND (EndDate >= @Date)

AND -- Added the "AND" here

CASE WHEN @day = 'Monday' THEN (Monday = 1)   -- Removed "AND" 
    WHEN @day = 'Tuesday' THEN (Tuesday = 1)  -- Removed "AND" 
    ELSE AND (Wednesday = 1) 
END
```

Comment: Thx for the edit Dylan.  I must have been channeling VB this morning.

Comment: Hi jklemmack,  I had tried this initially and got an "Incorrect syntax near '='" error in the top line of the case statement.  Still getting that when I execute this query