# SQL query error CASE statement in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I need to have a `WHERE` condition in a stored procedure with a `CASE` expression.  I tried the below, but I get an error at the `=` sign on the third line.  Please, can someone correct me / point me to examples of a similar scenario?

```
WHERE CASE WHEN @Param1 IS null THEN (
  (@Param1 = '(All)')
  OR (@Param1 = '(Ready)' AND t.Column1 NOT IN ('Descoped','Done'))
  OR (@Param1 = '(Pending)' AND t.Column1 NOT IN ('Descoped','Done')
    AND t.Column2 IN ('Deferred','Rejected','Ready for Test'))
  OR (@Param1 = t.Column1 )
ELSE (
  t.Column1 = 'WIP'
  OR t.Column1 ='Not Started'
) END
```

The query is just for representation.  I am using MS SQL 2008 R2.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to accomplish with this...

Comment: Looks like there's a missing `)` before `ELSE`

Comment: possible duplicate of [case statement in where clause - SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730933/case-statement-in-where-clause-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put conditions inside of `case` in most SQL dialects (including SQL Server). In general, if you're using `case` in a `where` clause at all, you're pursuing a poor solution. The right way to do this is to rewrite the whole thing using Boolean logic:

```
WHERE  ( @Param1 IS NOT NULL 
         AND ( @Param1 IN ( '(All)', t.column1 ) 
                OR ( @Param1 = '(Ready)' 
                     AND t.column1 NOT IN ( 'Descoped', 'Done' ) ) 
                OR ( @Param1 = '(Pending)' 
                     AND t.column1 NOT IN ( 'Descoped', 'Done' ) 
                     AND t.column2 IN ( 'Deferred', 'Rejected', 'Ready for Test' ) ) ) ) 
        OR ( @Param1 IS NULL 
             AND t.column1 IN ( 'WIP', 'Not Started' ) )
```

For that matter, checking is see if `@Param1` is not null is kind of pointless. Since `null = anything` is always false, all of the conditions in the first half of the query will return false in `@Param1` is null. This should accomplish what you're attempting in a more straight-forward manner:

```
WHERE  @Param1 IN ( '(All)', t.column1 ) 
        OR ( @Param1 = '(Ready)' 
             AND t.column1 NOT IN ( 'Descoped', 'Done' ) ) 
        OR ( @Param1 = '(Pending)' 
             AND t.column1 NOT IN ( 'Descoped', 'Done' ) 
             AND t.column2 IN ( 'Deferred', 'Rejected', 'Ready for Test' ) ) 
        OR ( @Param1 IS NULL 
             AND t.column1 IN ( 'WIP', 'Not Started' ) )
```

Comment: Thanks Allan! The problem was its an old sp i was trying to do it with minimum changes. I have used the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

Case in SQL returns a value. It is not a control flow. If you need to match different condition based on a variable you probably should write something like this

```
select * from myTable t
where t.id =
case when @Param1 is null then
    2
else
    1
End
```